# Heroku Django Postgresql database admin, where is the super user?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I know it's quite newbie, but I just started using heroku. Please bear with me.

If you develop on heroku, it provides you postgresql with username and password.

However when you access it from your django admin page using that, it returns:

```
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user..
```

My question is what do you have to do to create the super user for the admin page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from a one off dyno

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#syncing-the-database before you do it though.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

instead of

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: What to do if `syncdb` command is unknown to manage.py while `migrate` has same error?

Answer (score 1):

you have to make makemigrations first and migrate

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations

heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

and you have to createsuperuser begining

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser u



username :*florbert

password:######
```